# How to avoid separators to be printed on screen when printing a whole array in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a strange issue with my script and I would like to know if it exists a solution to get rid of it.

I have put this in a script for you to test it out :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clear the screen
clear

# Define the array
ARRAY=("\e[2;3HLine one" "\e[3;3HLine two" "\e[4;3HLine three")

# Change background color to "teal" and foreground color to "black"
echo -e "\e[0;30m\e[46m"

# Print each line one by one on the screen
# This works as expected, nothing to say
echo -e "${ARRAY[0]}"
echo -e "${ARRAY[1]}"
echo -e "${ARRAY[2]}"

# The exact same text, just moved the text below the previous one to make it easier to compare
ARRAY=("\e[6;3HLine one" "\e[7;3HLine two" "\e[8;3HLine three")
# Print the entire array in one shot, to gain speed
# This does not work as expected as there is a "space" at the end of the 2 first lines
echo -e "${ARRAY[@]}"

# Reset the colors to normal
echo -e "\e[0m"
```

When launching it, you can see in the 2nd printing there is a "space" at the end of the 1st and 2nd line.

The question is : **How to get rid of these spaces ?!**

Note : I need this formating and I need to print the whole array at once... And by the way, I already played with IFS and character substitution but nothing worked as expected so far...

**EDIT :** The solution proposed by Cyrus just below using "**printf**" instead of "**echo**" seems to work as expected (I'm not sure of the pros and cons of using it instead of "echo" builtin but for now it will do the job).

Solution :

```
printf "%b\n" "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Instead of :

```
echo -e "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Thanks again Cyrus for your help.

Comment: If you removed the ANSI escape codes, you would see that the array expansion would print on one line, with each element separated by a space (being the first character of the default value of `IFS`). Using ANSI escape codes to reposition the cursor while printing doesn't change the behavior of the parameter expansion.

Comment: @chepner Yes I saw that during my investigations (take a look at my note concerning `IFS`) but as I mentioned, I need this positioning so I was looking for a way to "remove" these spaces when printing that way. Thanks anyway for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
echo -e "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

by

```
printf "%b\n" "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works as expected. As a side question, is printf quicker or slower than echo command ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Both are bash builtins.

Comment: No problem, I'll maybe run some tests if I need. Thanks again.